# Is there a website that will allow me to filter tweets from my Twitter feed?

Tags: twitter, filter, feed

I need to approve/reject tweets from my Twitter feed, and display on our website.  Any websites out there that will provide this functionality?

I've looked into TidyTweet.com, but I can't tell if they support the kind of "feed" we have (it's actually a json search, not an RSS feed).

For example, this is our "feed":
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Downtown+Chicago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitterfeed already provides an interface for that. Click on `edit`->`advanced` you should see filter tweets.

Another alternative is filtering from the feed itself, you can do this from [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com)

Comment: I'm really looking for something with an interface that allows one-off accept/reject capability (not automatic keyword filtering).  Also, I tried to setup a TwitterFeed with the json Twitter search I posted above, but it gave me an error about not having a publish date in the results. (I think Twitter Feed is for RSS feeds specifically)